# Vuejs public folder vs laravel storage/app/public to store images

Tags: laravel, image, vue.js, laravel-5

I am trying to store images in project/public/imgs folder but laravel always store images in project/storage/app/public/imgs.

I am using Vuejs with laravel so, i have to store images in the above mentioned folder. i have make changes in config/filesysytem.php but it does not work.
please tell me where i am wrong. here are two screenshots of my changes.

Project structure:
https://gyazo.com/f5126911583b7ac6c27cff4f58802975

Config/Filesystem.php:
https://gyazo.com/290ae9b3ccce640c8b9c06aac5346706

Comment: How did you build your Vue app? Did you use `vue-cli`?

Comment: I am using webpack and vue-cli. @MattOestreich